# Can't find resource file after exporting to a runnable JAR

Tags: java, xtend

I have a project structure that looks like this:

```
Tester  
\-- src  
    |-- hello.java  
    \-- vocabulary.csv
```

I load the csv file using getResource:

```
url = this.getClass().getResource("vocabulary.csv");
System.out.println(url.getPath());
new FileReader(url.getPath());
```

The program works completly fine until I export the project to a runnable jar file. Even though the URL is still valid (he prints the path instead of null) the console shows this:

```
jar:file:/home/malte/Desktop/vocs.jar!/main/vocabulary.csv
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/malte/Desktop/vocs.jar!/main/vocabulary.csv (No such file or directory)
```

Can you explain me why this happens and how I can solv the issue?

P.S. I am using Xtend instead of pure Java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use

`InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream();`

once you package your source as a jar. You have just one file : `your jar`. Your `vocabulary.csv` is no longer a standalone file on filesystem anymore.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thanks! And instead of **new FileReader(url.getPath())** I now use **new InputStreamReader(is)**

Comment: This solution doesn't work. Also tried with URL. I have used Eclipse IDE Export option and chose "Package jars" when exported all the necessary dependencies